# DateListPlot from DateHistogram

Tags: plotting, histograms

How do I draw a `DateListPlot` from the bin height and bin middle position? I have a series of time events from which I calculate `DateHistogram`, but I want to represent the result through a kind `DateListPlot`, with joined line.

Example:

```
data = {DateObject[{2015, 6, 10}], DateObject[{2015, 6, 26}], 
DateObject[{2015, 6, 15}], DateObject[{2015, 6, 25}], 
DateObject[{2015, 6, 23}], DateObject[{2015, 6, 19}], 
DateObject[{2015, 5, 31}], DateObject[{2015, 6, 6}], 
DateObject[{2015, 6, 4}], DateObject[{2015, 6, 16}], 
DateObject[{2015, 5, 29}], DateObject[{2015, 6, 4}], 
DateObject[{2015, 6, 14}], DateObject[{2015, 6, 3}], 
DateObject[{2015, 6, 14}], DateObject[{2015, 6, 6}], 
DateObject[{2015, 6, 10}], DateObject[{2015, 6, 19}], 
DateObject[{2015, 6, 20}], DateObject[{2015, 6, 21}]};

histogram = DateHistogram[data, "Day"]
```

How do I convert it to a kind of `DateListPlot` with joined line, where each point is the bin height and bin middle position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `Reap` and `Sow` with the functional height syntax of `DateHistogram`.

```
{dh, {{bins, counts}}} = 
    Reap[DateHistogram[data, "Day", Function[{b, c}, Sow[b]; Sow[c]]]];

Show[dh, DateListPlot[Select[Last@# != 0 &]@Transpose@{Mean /@ bins, counts}]]
```

[image]

This uses the functional height syntax to return the bins and counts that `DateHistogram` has calculated internally. You can think of it as hooking the internal date version of `HistogramList`. It returns the counts (`c`) without altering them so you get the expected histogram; `b` are the bins.

There is similar code in `Histogram`'s documentation in the *Application* section's *Create a ListLinePlot using counts extracted from a histogram*.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You want some kind of `DateHistogramList` function that works like [`HistogramList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HistogramList.html) does, but I don't see an option for it.  Without that, you could just extract the coordinates for the tops of the [`Rectangle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle.html)s in the histogram.

```
histogramDatelistplot = 
 Cases[histogram, 
   Rectangle[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, __] | 
     RectangleBox[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, __] :> {Mean[{x1, x2}], y2},
    Infinity] // DateListPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The code needed to modified because for some bin specifications (like "Day"), the histogram uses `Rectangle` while for others ("Month") it uses `RectangleBox".  You can show them together,

```
Show[histogram, histogramDatelistplot]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ok, thanks. Even so why is your example is not working when the option "Day" to "Month"?

Comment: To figure that out, look at the results from `histogram // InputForm` - this will show the full code needed to produce the plot.  For some unknown reason, when you use "Month" it uses `RectangleBox` instead of `Rectangle`.  So what you need to do is change `Rectangle[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, __]` to `Rectangle[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, __] | 
 RectangleBox[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, __]` and now it will match both patterns.

Comment: Ok, it's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the third argument of `DateHistogram` to extract bins and heights and use them in `DateListPlot` as `Epilog`:

```
DateHistogram[data, "Day", (((dl = Transpose[{Mean/@#, #2}]); #2)&),  
 Epilog -> First[DateListPlot[dl, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]]]]
```

[image]

If you want to remove bars with zero heigth, use

```
DateHistogram[data, "Day", (((dl = Transpose[{Mean /@ #, #2}]); #2)&), 
 Epilog -> First[DateListPlot[DeleteCases[dl, {_, 0}], PlotStyle->Directive[Thick, Red]]]]
```

[image]